# Dropdown not expanding even after having values

Tags: reactjs

I am facing an issue where my 2nd dropdown is receiving values but is not expanding:-

```html
class clusterServersDropdown extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clusterslist: [],
      servertype: [],
      selectserver: "",
      selectcluster: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        clusterslist:[
            {label: "cluster1", servertype:["test1","test2","test3"]},
            {label: "cluster2", servertype:["test1","test2","test3"]},
            {label: "cluster3", servertype:["test1","test2","test3"]},
        ]
    });
  }
  selectclusterChange(e) {
    console.log(e.label)
    this.setState({ selectcluster: e.label },() =>{
      console.log(this.state.selectcluster)
    });
   
    this.setState({
      servertype: this.state.clusterslist.find(
        (x) => x.label === e.label
      ).servertype
    },() =>{
      console.log(this.state.servertype)
    }
    );    
  }

  routeChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.label)
        this.setState({ selectserver: e.label}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.selectserver);
        let path = "/inventory/cluster/" + this.state.selectcluster +"/servertype/" + this.state.selectserver;
        console.log(path);
        this.props.history.push(path);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <label>
            Select cluster and server type
              <Select className="react-select" classNamePrefix="react-select"
                onChange={this.selectclusterChange.bind(this)}
                options={this.state.clusterslist.map((x) => {
                  return {label: x.label};
                })}
              />
              <Select className="react-select" classNamePrefix="react-select" 
                onChange={this.routeChange.bind(this)}
                options={this.state.servertype.map((y) => {
                  return {label: y};
                })}
              />
          </label>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default withRouter(clusterServersDropdown);
```

Please see below snaps:-
[image]

Whenever I am clicking on the 2nd dropdown it retracts and am not able to select the value and proceed. Strangely this works if i replace label by h5, see as below:-
[image]

Am i using label wrongly?

Comment: Check if ```return {label: y};``` statement on your second ```<Select>``` is correct or not. You have mentioned ```return {label: x.label};``` on your first ```<Select>``` which tells me that the second ```<Select>``` might have ```return {label: y.label};``` maybe?

Comment: Hi thanks for checking, so I have posted my whole code, in case of x i returned x.label as it had the values as a key, but when i select cluster1 from it, then only i want other dropdown values to be listed, and as that's a 3 element list, hence i cant print its label hence i selected y to return.

Comment: Got it. Can you update your question to include the ```routeChange()``` function too?

Comment: Added the same.

Comment: One thing I can notice right off the bat is that you aren't doing ```this.routeChange.bind(this)```. Try doing this.

Comment: Did that, still the same. Strangely this works if i use h5 instead of label. So some issue with label functionality that am using.

Comment: Shouldn't be because the first ```<Select>``` works fine right?

Comment: yes select works fine, only difference is replacing label by h5, and that solves the issue.

Comment: Are you talking about the ```<label>``` tag? If that's so then I'd suggest removing it completely.

Comment: Yes have removed label completely, will look for some other alternative. Thanks for help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241353/discussion-between-sarvesh-agarwal-and-arjis-chakraborty).

Answer (score 0):

Removed label and used h5 with some font formatting instead.

```html
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h5 style={{'font-family':"Pacifico"}}>
            Select cluster and server type from dropdown to view its inventory
              <Select className="react-select" classNamePrefix="react-select"
                onChange={this.selectclusterChange.bind(this)}
                options={this.state.clusterslist.map((x) => {
                  return {label: x.label};
                })}
              />
              <Select className="react-select" classNamePrefix="react-select" 
                onChange={this.routeChange}
                options={this.state.servertype.map((y) => {
                  return {label: y};
                })}
              />
            </h5>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working as expected now.